# Get the file size of an Image

Tags: c#, image

I search to get the file size (in bytes) of an image in C# :

I get the image in a base64 string, but in this format I have the impression it's no possible to get the file size.

So I transforme it in an image object like this :

```
// Convert Base64 String to byte[]
byte[] imageBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(imageSrc);
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);

// Convert byte[] to Image
ms.Write(imageBytes, 0, imageBytes.Length);
Image imageObj = Image.FromStream(ms, true);
```

But i'm not able to get the file size. I can have the dimensions or the type but not the file size.

Have you got an idea on that please?

Comment: You'll have to save it to a `MemoryStream` first, and get the stream's length. Just remember that the size depends on the format you choose to save the image in.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You already have the size of your image in bytes, you can get it like this:

`imageBytes.Length`

As I understood, you don't want to convert it to another format, just save it, so you can save your bytes directly to your file, the simplest solution:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string yourpath, byte[] yourbytes)
```

Comment: When I check for imageBytes.Length I get the result 232019 whereas my Image is 581kb!

Comment: +1. Note that it is size of original file. If you load bytes into Image and than save it most likely size will be different due to different file formats/compression.

Comment: Yes this will give you the size of your original image, in it's original format, do you want to save it in another format? If not, just write the bytes you get to a file, you don't even need the `Image` object

Comment: In fact, I use FILE API so I get a base 64 string that I send by a webservice in javascript.  

Before sending the image I have to delete the first part :
image = image.replace(/^data:image\/(png|jpg|gif);base64,/, "");

The image I upload is a Jpeg format and I save in Jpeg format too so I don't understand the differents size I receive

Comment: The `Image` object decodes the image from the bytes, and stores it in `Bitmap` non compressed format, that's why you have a difference in size when you use it. That's also why you shouldn't use it if you only want to store the file without converting it to another format, because you won't get a better quality, but you'll use more space for storage.

Comment: I have a Stream object. Can i get the original image size from the stream itself instead of converting it to bytes.. and reading its length?

Comment: @Thameem I think you should post a new question about this, it depends on your context: do you want to get the size of the image from a base 64 string or is this another scenario ?